# Cloud readiness - looking for HTTP Session alternatives

Tags: spring-cloud, software-design, saas, paas, cloud-foundry

We are planning to refactor our `J2EE` `Monolith` into `Microservices`application. We are planning to build using `Spring`, `Spring boot`, `Spring cloud` and `Pivotal cloud foundry` as `PaaS`.

When i was validating whether my current application is cloud ready using  [The twelve-factor app](https://12factor.net/) , the important think i noticed is the usuage of 'HTTP Sessions' in our application. The link suggestes

> Some web systems rely on “sticky sessions” – that is, caching user
>   session data in memory of the app’s process and expecting future
>   requests from the same visitor to be routed to the same process.
>   Sticky sessions are a violation of twelve-factor and should never be
>   used or relied upon. Session state data is a good candidate for a
>   datastore that offers time-expiration, such as Memcached or Redis.

I don't understand how can  i use `im-memory data store` to track the user session? Could someone please explain? Should i use some unique key for users to retrieve information form in-memory data store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good example, you can have a look on this explanation of Spring Session implementation

https://www.infoq.com/articles/Next-Generation-Session-Management-with-Spring-Session

It has a reference to Redis storage, which you can bind to your application from PCF services.